# jQuery - how to fetch data from JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am detecting when is finish an action in a form, like this:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#file').change(function() {
      alert('Done');
    });
  });
```

When the action is done, I see the alert message **Done**. That's cool.
When this action is done, I would like to fetch data that are in there - and here's the problem - I don't know how.

I see the data in Firebug:
[image: screenshot]

How can I access them?

Comment: Actually, I have no AJAX call so far. This is all what I have so far.

Comment: we need more context.

Answer (score 1):

try 

`$(this).url
or
$(this).attr("url");`

Comment: But how to use this for obtaining data? Sorry, I am not very experienced this way.

Comment: Hi please check this demo
http://jsfiddle.net/MfSes/
Please let me know what all you want to get from it

Comment: Thank you, when I try this, I'll get this: `Object[input#item_file_url property value = "https://www.filepicker....le/12334..." attribute value = "null"]`. There are missing some elements, but how to obtain for example just the URL?

Comment: Check this 

http://jsfiddle.net/MfSes/3/

You cant take much more information about the file 
only few things like size,name,url etc

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler for `ajaxSuccess` and then see the arugments.

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
     console.log(arguments);
});
```

Probably data will be `arguments[3]`.

Comment: I've tried that, but I've got always just **undefined** message (when I tried to alert the argument).

Comment: @user984621 What does `arguments` contain?

Answer (score 0):

file to upload selected -> alert('Done'),

file uploaded to server -> server responce:

```
    {
        "data": [{
            "url": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/0pD7xDQdQXOPLamnoNee", 
            "data": {
                "size": 162488, 
                "type": "image/x-icon", 
                "key": "AtON5s2QE2AsYiBnYOzw_filetoupload", 
                "filename": "filetoupload"
            }
        }], 
        "result": "ok"
    }
```

Example of ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/uploadurl',
    data: {data: data},
    success: function(data){
        //this data you are trying to get
        //to access filename -> data.data[0].data.filename
    }
})
```